# Remove list of users from list of groups, BUT users from a different domain (foreign security principals)

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I have a list of accounts (SAM account names) and a list of groups all the accounts need to be removed from.  My problem is that I have to specify -server DC01 since the users are in a different domain.  I can do that for removing 1 user at a time with:

```
$Groups = Get-Content C:\temp\groups.txt
$user = get-aduser <username> -Server "DC01.domain.com"

foreach ($Group in $Groups) {
    Write-Host "Removing $user from $group" -Foreground Yellow
    Remove-ADGroupMember -Identity $group -Members $user -Confirm:$false
}
```

But I have several long lists of users, and there's got to be a way to do this for all of them.

I tried adding the ** entries below, but no dice:

```
$Groups = Get-Content C:\temp\groups.txt
$user = Get-Content C:\temp\users0.txt **-Server "DC01.domain.com"**


foreach ($Group in $Groups) {
    Write-Host "Removing $user from $group" -Foreground Yellow
    Remove-ADGroupMember -Identity $group -Members $user **-searchbase = "DC=domain,DC=com"** -Confirm:$false
}
```

Thanks in advance for any suggestions!

Comment: What would be in the `C:\temp\users0.txt` file. The users DistinghuishedNames? (I think you need those in an array and use `Remove-ADGroupMember -Identity $group -Members $userDN -Confirm:$false`)

Comment: The users0.txt file will contain their sam account names

Comment: Actually, I originally had a list of diplay names, but assumed I needed SAM account names, if not SIDs or DNs.  I have a way to get the SAM account names, so I did that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cannot test this right now, but I believe you can set the `-Members` parameter to an array of users.

Apparently, the `Remove-ADGroupMember` does not work if you supply an array of DistinguishedNames when the users are from another domain, so we need to use the full default (Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.ADUser) objects as returned by the `Get-ADUser` cmdlet.

```
$DCGroups = (Get-ADDomain your.domainA.com).PDCEmulator    # get a PDC emulator in domain A where the groups are
$DCUsers  = (Get-ADDomain your.domainB.com).PDCEmulator    # get a PDC emulator in domain B where the users are

$Groups = Get-Content 'C:\temp\groups.txt'                 # the groups are in domainA                 

# get an array users ADUser Objects from Domain B
$users = Get-Content 'C:\temp\users0.txt' | ForEach-Object { 
            $user = Get-ADUser -Filter "SamAccountName -eq '$_'" -Server $DCUsers -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
            if ($user) { $user }
         }

# remove these users from the groups in Domain A
foreach ($Group in $Groups) {
    Write-Host "Removing $($users.Count) users from $Group" -Foreground Yellow
    Remove-ADGroupMember -Identity $Group -Members $users -Confirm:$false -Server $DCGroups
}
```

---

**Edit**

To overcome the exception being thrown when you try to remove a user that is not a member of the group, you need to add some extra code to make sure the `-Members` parameter of `Remove-ADGroupMember` contains only ADUser objects that currently are member of this group.

```
$DCGroups = (Get-ADDomain your.domainA.com).PDCEmulator    # get a PDC emulator in domain A where the groups are
$DCUsers  = (Get-ADDomain your.domainB.com).PDCEmulator    # get a PDC emulator in domain B where the users are

$Groups = Get-Content 'C:\temp\groups.txt'                 # the groups are in domainA                 

# get an array users ADUser Objects from Domain B
$users = Get-Content 'C:\temp\users0.txt' | ForEach-Object { 
            $user = Get-ADUser -Filter "SamAccountName -eq '$_'" -Server $DCUsers -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
            if ($user) { $user }
         }
# remove these users from the groups in Domain A
foreach ($Group in $Groups) {
    # get a list of SamAccountNames of users that are currently a member of this group
    $members = Get-ADGroupMember -Identity $Group | Where-Object {$_.objectClass -eq 'user'} | Select-Object -ExpandProperty SamAccountName
    # create a subset of users that are indeed in the members list
    $removeThese = @($users | Where-Object { $members -contains $_.SamAccountName })
    if ($removeThese.Count) {
        Write-Host "Removing $($removeThese.Count) users from $Group" -Foreground Yellow
        Remove-ADGroupMember -Identity $Group -Members $removeThese -Confirm:$false -Server $DCGroups
    }
    else {
        Write-Host "No users need to be removed from group '$Group' " -Foreground Green
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried it and it returns this error:  Remove-ADGroupMember : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Members'. The argument is null or empty. Provide an
argument that is not null or empty, and then try the command again.

Comment: To test this, I ran ```$userDN = Get-Content 'C:\temp\users0.txt' | ForEach-Object { 
              $user = Get-ADUser -Filter "SamAccountName -eq '$_'" -Server "dc01.domain.com"
              if ($user) { $user.DistinghuishedName }
          }```  Then I ran ```$user | Select-Object Name | Format-Table -AutoSize``` to see what it showed and strangely it only showed the last SAM account name in the list (of 31)

Comment: @DanielGower Without knowing the inputfile, `$userDN` should be a string array of user  distinguished names. Can you check that?

Comment: @DanielGower Aha,  I misspelled `DistinguishedName`. I have fixed that in the code now.

Comment: Ah, I missed that too!  Ok, so it definitely made better progress, but it gets stuck on the fact that the user accounts are not in the domain that I'm running the script from:  Remove-ADGroupMember : Cannot find an object with identity: 'CN=last\, first,OU=domain0,OU=Linked
Accounts,DC=domain1,DC=com' under: 'DC=domain2,DC=domain3,DC=com'.

Comment: @DanielGower Can you try adding `-Server "DC01.domain.com"` to the `Remove-AdGroupMember` cmdlet too?

Comment: @DanielGower I did some digging around and found that using DistinguishedNames will not work when removing users cross-domain. I have replaced the code to now use the ADUser objects instead.

Comment: This worked!  initially I entered a DC server for <your.domainA.com>, which caused an error.  I changed it to domain.com and it worked!  This is beautiful!  Thank you very much, Theo!

Comment: As a follow up, if/when there's a user who is not in a group, it outputs "Remove-ADGroupMember : The specified account name is not a member of the group" and apparently stops parsing the list of users.  The script seems to stop when it hist a user that's not in one of the groups.

Comment: @DanielGower Please see my edit. The new code now makes sure the users to remove are members of the group. This will avoid the exception being thrown.

Comment: Much appreciated, Theo!